# Problems with DSolve

Tags: differential-equations

I'm trying to solve and plot a second order ODE. Here is my code:

```
DSolve[y''[x] + 4 y'[x] + 12 y[x] == 80 Sin[2 x], y[x], x]
```

Problem 1... it sticks me with a wacky answer:

> {{y[x] ->     E^(-2 x) C[2] Cos[2 Sqrt[2] x] + 
>       E^(-2 x) C[1] Sin[
>         2 Sqrt[2]
>           x] + (5 (2 Cos[2 Sqrt[2] x] Cos[2 (-1 + Sqrt[2]) x] + 
>            Sqrt[2] Cos[2 Sqrt[2] x] Cos[2 (-1 + Sqrt[2]) x] - 
>            2 Cos[2 Sqrt[2] x] Cos[2 (1 + Sqrt[2]) x] + 
>            Sqrt[2] Cos[2 Sqrt[2] x] Cos[2 (1 + Sqrt[2]) x] - 
>            Sqrt[2] Cos[2 (-1 + Sqrt[2]) x] Sin[2 Sqrt[2] x] + 
>            Sqrt[2] Cos[2 (1 + Sqrt[2]) x] Sin[2 Sqrt[2] x] + 
>            Sqrt[2] Cos[2 Sqrt[2] x] Sin[2 (-1 + Sqrt[2]) x] - 
>            Sqrt[2] Cos[2 Sqrt[2] x] Sin[2 (1 + Sqrt[2]) x] - 
>            2 Sin[2 Sqrt[2] x] Sin[2 (1 + Sqrt[2]) x] + 
>            Sqrt[2] Sin[2 Sqrt[2] x] Sin[2 (1 + Sqrt[2]) x] - 
>            2 Sin[2 Sqrt[2] x] Sin[2 x - 2 Sqrt[2] x] - 
>            Sqrt[2] Sin[2 Sqrt[2] x] Sin[2 x - 2 Sqrt[2] x]))/(Sqrt[
>          2] (-2 + Sqrt[2]) (2 + Sqrt[2]))}}

Which is very different from what I solved on paper:

> $x(t)=e^{-2x}(c_1\cos{(2\sqrt{2}x)}+c_2\sin{(2\sqrt{2}x)})+5\sin{(5x)}-5cos{(2x)}$

Problem 2... When I try to give it initial values so I can plot something, I enter this:

```
DSolve[{y''[x] + 4 y'[x] + 12 y[x] == 80 Sin[2 x], y'[0] == 0, 
  y[0] = 5}, y[x], x]
```

And get this in return:

> Equation or list of equations expected instead of True in the first argument `{12 y[x]+4 y'[x]+y^''[x]==80 Sin[2 x],True,5}`

Sorry if this is a bit disorganized. Hopefully you can follow my logic.

Comment: Do a `FullSimplify` on result...

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Also, `y[0] = 5` should be `y[0] == 5`.

Comment: And do a ClearAll[y] before you try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FullSimplify[DSolve[y''[x] + 4 y'[x] + 12 y[x] == 80 Sin[2 x], y[x], x]]

(* 
  {{y[x] -> -5 Cos[2 x] + 5 Sin[2 x] + E^(-2 x) 
              (C[2] Cos[2 Sqrt[2] x] + C[1] Sin[2 Sqrt[2] x])}}
*)
```

For the second problem...

```
DSolve[{y''[x] + 4 y'[x] + 12 y[x] == 80 Sin[2 x], y'[0] == 0, y[0] == 5}, y[x], x]
```

(note use of `==`, you have an `=`...)

Comment: Great! FullSimplify works, but the single = was actually just a transcription error. Even when I use your exact code it gives a similar error. Now y'[0]==0 evaluates as True while y[0]==5 seems to be fine.